# Functoriality of internal hom of chain complexes

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

The [internal hom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom+of+chain+complexes) of chain complexes $[-,-]$ is supposed to form a bifunctor
$$\operatorname{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Mod}_R)^\mathrm{op} \times \operatorname{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Mod}_R) \to \operatorname{Ch}_\bullet(\mathsf{Mod}_R).$$

The boundary map on $[X,Y]$ distributes over function composition as $d(\sigma \circ \tau ) = (d\sigma) \circ \tau + (-1)^{|\sigma|} \sigma \circ d\tau$.

Functoriality in the first variable says that a chain map $W_\bullet \xrightarrow{f} X_\bullet[k]$  should induce a *chain map*

$$[X_\bullet, Y_\bullet] \xrightarrow{f^*} [W_\bullet, Y_\bullet[k]] = [W_\bullet, Y_\bullet][k] \qquad \qquad   \scriptscriptstyle{\dashleftarrow \text{ or should this be $-k$? Doesn't seem to matter}}$$

Now if $\sigma \in [X_\bullet, Y_\bullet]$ of degree $j$, then 
$$\require{cancel} d^{\operatorname{[W_\bullet,Y_{\bullet}][k]}}( \sigma \circ f) = (-1)^k d^{\operatorname{[W_\bullet,Y_{\bullet}]}}(\sigma \circ f) = (-1)^k \left( d\sigma \circ f + (-1)^{|\sigma|}\sigma \circ \cancel{df} \right) = (-1)^k d\sigma \circ f$$
$$ \neq d \sigma \circ f$$
So it seems not to be a chain map. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functoriality in the first variable only says that for $k = 0$ (morphisms have degree $0$). If $f$ is a morphism of degree $k$ then it induces a map

$$[X[k], Y] \to [W, Y]$$

and there are some signs involved in moving this shift $[k]$ around.

Comment: Oh! OK, so the $\operatorname{Hom}_{\operatorname{Ch}_\bullet (\mathsf{Mod}_R)}$ sets only form an abelian group, not a graded abelian group?

Comment: @Eric: yes, although now that you have the internal hom around, chain complexes are now enriched over themselves, and you can ask for "internal functoriality" rather than just functoriality.

Comment: Suppose I view $f$ as a map from $W[-k] \to X$, and it induces a map $[X,Y] \to [W[-k], Y]$. Why isn't that the same as inducing a map $[X,Y] \to [W,Y][k]$? Maybe this is where the signs in moving the shift come in. Where can I read about those? Can't seem to find them in any references.

Comment: Oh, now I think I see the difference...$[W[-k], Y] = [W, Y[k]]$ has a boundary map that differs from that of $[W, Y][k]$ by $(-1)^k$. So to turn one into the other I should have to alter the boundary map by $(-1)^k$. Right?